# How to get Pivot Table - Calculated Field to work in this excel sheet?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

first time asking a question here. So I apologize in advance if I have not asked properly.

I have a set of data in the form of a table, which I have converted into a Pivot Table, with the normal purchase sales and profit columns. However, my problem arises as I want to create another column in the Pivot Table which gives the profit percentage on purchases. I am aware that this can be done by clicking on the Fields, Items & Sets drop-down menu under the PivotTable Tools - Analyze Tab, However, this doesn't work and all I can see is that the Calculated Field option is greyed out.

Can anyone advise how I can get a profit percentage column to be inserted in the pivot table? Thank you in advance.

Warren Barrell

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPItz.png)

Comment: Did my answer below solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PivotTable uses an OLAP data source, which is why that option is greyed out. If you have the requisite version/SKU of Excel you could use the PowerPivot add-in to write a measure, but otherwise I think your only other option is to get your database admin to add the column to the database, and then bring that through to Excel.